# Linux virtual device driver using serial

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, usbserial

I'm trying to search for sample code of Linux virtual device driver using serial.

I have the following requirements:

1. Embedded board and certain controller are connected with USB-serial.
2. The device driver(embedded board) sends data via serial. (not to userspace)
3. The device driver(embedded board) received data as ack via serial. (not from userspace)
4. The device driver(embedded board) shows manipulated data on sysfs.

My question is
  Is there any reference code that I can follow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may look at 'serdev' subsystem. It is intended to drive devices connected over serial, which is not directly your use case, but something similar.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try serdev.